# How To Make Objects Stick To Character?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

(I'm Using Unity 2018.4.15f1)

So I'm making a remake of a game called "The Wonderful End Of The World" (here's the game trailer for context: https://youtu.be/iwAplTdYBlo).

the only way I know how to recreate the absorbing effect is that the object randomly selects a waypoint for the object to go to.

here is a pic of the avatar I made:
[Avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9irbn.png)

So can anyone help me with this? (IDK tbh because what I am aiming for is pretty obscure)

edit: I should say that I am an Amateur and can barely write a piece of code without a tutorial

Comment: Hi @horse music. You might get better answers if you can reframe this as a more specific question/to be more explicit about what you're asking - presumably for some details about the absorbing effect. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For the player you should create a child for each one of the joints of your character. When you want to absorb an object you should then randomize a number between 1 and the number of joints and each number will correspond to one of the joints.

Once you have this number generated you can move the object with a Lerp or a transform or with any method you are used to and reach the position of the joint you have found.

Then you could easily set the object as a child of that joint so you can manage objects and joints in a much more flexible way.

If you want to create an effect like in your previous game you can add some offsets variables for the position of the joint and so the object will randomly go to a position near the joint and it will look way better

Comment: I didn't make The Wonderful End Of The World. Dejobaan Games did

Comment: Uh ok, but my advice should work the same ;) @horse_music

Answer (score 0):

At least for proof of concept I would try doing:

- Each object instance (that can stick to the player) have a script that deals with the sticking with something like:
  a flag (bool) set to false, activating the sticking set the flag to true and disables the objects rigidBody's gravity (or sets it to 0)
  while the flag is false on the onUpdate constantly add a force to the object in the direction of the player (start with the players local 0 and figure out later how you want it to look) and play with it (maybe using slerp or lerp) to make it stronger the closer it gets?
- a trigger collider (a simple box collider set to trigger) around the player's object that set every "object that can stick" that enter its collider to trigger the sticking activation method (flag+no gravity)
  you can use a tag for those objects that you want to be able to stick so in the OnTriggerEnter you simply check if it has this tag name.